# How can I Open PDF files (window default program Adobe Reader) through Delphi 2009?

Tags: delphi, pdf, delphi-2009, shellexecute, adobe-reader

So basically when I try to open up PDF files that are windows defaulted to open with Adobe Reader nothing happens.  If I set the default program to Internet Explorer it works..

Here is my code

```
var
openDialog : TOpenDialog;    // Open dialog variable
begin
  openDialog := TOpenDialog.Create(self);
  openDialog.InitialDir := MaskEditLocation.Text;
  if openDialog.Execute then
   ShellExecute(Handle, PChar('Open'), PChar(openDialog.FileName), nil, nil,
   SW_SHOWNORMAL);
  openDialog.Free;
end;
```

Any Ideas?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Long ago, I remember Acrobat Reader not working if `ShellExecute` was called while the application was being debugged, but it worked fine when the application ran "normally."

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You should never presume that the application has registered a specific verb like `open` or `run`. Just leave the verb empty when you want the default behavior, and let Windows decide:

```
ShellExecute(Handle, nil, PChar(OpenDialog.FileName), nil,  nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

Comment: I would use 'open' ...no reason to not use the open verb.

...and I do not see a difference between this and what he is currently doing.

Comment: @GDF: Read my answer. Not all applications define an `open` verb, and `open` may not be the default. Read the words I wrote. :-) Also, read the MSDN documentation on ShellExecute for yourself. (And the difference is in the second parameter to `ShellExecute`.) Like I said, if you want the **default** behavior, leave the verb empty and Windows will automatically give you the **default** behavior (the same thing you'd get by double-clicking the file in Windows Explorer).

Comment: I see what you are saying, so if Adobe Reader does not define an open, this will be the same as a double click. However, since I know adobe reader defines an 'open', among other verbs this just seemed like an odd response to me...   ...it's all good...

Comment: @GDF, the major difference is that Acrobat Reader actually opens the file this way, while the original question's way does not. :-) And I was referring to a general rule, not Reader in particular - if you want the **default** behavior, don't ask for a **specific** action.

Comment: Thats good to know that I can just leave the verb empty and let windows decide.  It works great!  Thanks everyone!

Comment: In 2018 but using Delphi 7 and XP so it matters. I also removed the 'open' and now magically works (Foxit reader).